# Looking for a .NET implementation of SearchBlox REST API

Tags: c#, lucene

I am exploring [SearchBlox](http://www.searchblox.com) (a webbased implementation of Lucene) and I want to use C# as the client.   I am wondering if there is already a C# implementation of the SearchBlox API for C#.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently building a sample site using XSLT. Its not a complete solution yet, but should get you in the right direction.

- Setup SearchBlox to return the results in XML.
- Grab XML result and apply a stylesheet to the XML.

[Download the source and check it out](https://github.com/robasta/SearchBlox-Powered-MVC-Site/zipball/master)